# I am trying to grep assuming multiple lines as single line in unix

Tags: grep

```
abc def \ 
ghi \
jkl mno pqr \
stu vwx yz
```

How can my grep command assume the above as single line and grep 'ghi' and return as below

```
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz
```

Comment: Is each backslash supposed to escape a newline character? In the example text, the first backslash has a space character after it. Does the input contain anything other than what you have shown?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `grep`:

```
$ grep -Eo '[a-z]+' file | paste -sd ' ' -
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz
```

Or regular `grep`:

```
$ grep -o '[a-z]\{1,\}' file | paste -sd ' ' -
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz
```

With `Perl`:

```
$ perl -0777 -nE 'say join " ", /\w+/g' file
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz
```